# Setting MongoDb collection name with Micronaut Annotation

Tags: java, mongodb, micronaut

I'm trying to connect a MongoDb Atlas Db to my Micronaut app but it doesn't return my saved items.
I'm using the @MongoRepository annotation to extend the supplied CrudRepository by micronaut.
Micronaut is able to connect to the MongoDb shards and after some testing the MongoClient connects to the right Database.

The Problem, I think, is that Micronaut doesn't fetch the right collection so it never returns anything.

I tried extending the @MongoRepository annotation with the dot-notation for collections (i.e. @MongoRepository(databaseName = "database.colletion")) but that didnt work either.

I don't really want to use the bare MongoClient and write the whole Repository myself, thats why I'm looking for a way to pass the collection name into the auto-generated repository.

My Repo Looks like this, I'm passing the connection string via application.yml:

```
@MongoRepository(databaseName = "recipes")
public interface RecipeRepository extends CrudRepository<Recipe, String> {

    //case-insensitive search using collations
    @MongoCollation("{locale: 'en', strength: 1}")
    @MongoFindQuery(filter = "{name: name}")
    List<Recipe> findByName(String name);

    @MongoCollation("{locale: 'en', strength: 1}")
    @MongoFindQuery(filter = "{ingredients.name: {$all: :ingredientNames}}")
    List<Recipe> findByIngredientsNames(List<String> ingredientNames);
}
```

After some research I found this class on Micronauts GitHub repo:

```
@Experimental
public interface MongoCollectionNameProvider {

    /**
     * Provides the MongoDB collection name based on the {@link PersistentEntity}.
     * @param persistentEntity The persistent entity that is associated to the collection
     * @return The collection name
     */
    @NonNull
    String provide(@NonNull PersistentEntity persistentEntity);

}
```

But I'm not sure how I can use it

Comment: you need to specify the collection name on the entity `Recipe` class and annotate it with `@MappedEntity` and specify the collection name in the annotation

Comment: @deadshot i sadly rewrote the whole repo but ill give it a try. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @deadshot I treid annotate the ```@MappedEntity``` annotation with my collection name but I'm not sure how you do this? Do you have an example i can refer to?

Comment: you can provide collection name like this `@MappedEntity(value = "<collection_name>")`